# Objective-C object placement iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, position

I have a GUI class extending UIViewController.

In its function `viewDidLoad`, I would like to have a `UITextField` instance. I would like that instance not aligned as a simple CGRect, setting its offset and width and height, but I want it rather to be resized dynamically, making it fill the whole width of the screen, with an offset of 5px from top, left and right each and a height of 20px. How is that done?

It should maintain the "relatively-absolute" positioning regardless of the device orientation, all orientations being supported.

Maybe there's something like a LayoutManager, as, for instance, GridBagLayout in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the `autoresizingMask` property of the view.

```
UIView *theParentView; // Assume this is the root view that owns the whole screen

CGRect textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(5, // Top-left corner x position
                                   5, // Top-left corner y position
                                   [theParentView bounds].width - 10, // Width
                                   20); // Height

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldFrame];

// This will make it resize with the parent view, maintaining margins
[myView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

[theParentView addSubview:myView];

[myView release];
```

This can all be done from Interface Builder as well. There's even a little animation showing how the view will resize in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a UIViewController itself isn't displayed, but it manages a hierarchy of view objects. You can create the text field in -viewDidLoad, but it needs to be added to the view controller's view before you can see it. You'd do something like this:

```
CGFloat inset = 5.0;
CGFloat fieldHeight = 20.0;
CGRect fieldRect = CGRectMake(inset,
                              inset,
                              self.view.size.width - (2 * inset),
                              fieldHeight);
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fieldRect];
field.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:field];
[field release];
```

Of course, if you need to refer to that field again later, you'll also want to stash a pointer to it in a property or ivar.

Comment: Why the fieldHeight + inset for the y value in CGRectMake? That would put it at 25, but in UIKit you want the top-left corner, not the bottom-left.

Comment: @BJ Homer, good catch -- thanks. I wish they hadn't flipped the coordinate system in Cocoa Touch!

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing as such built into the OS. I have seen a couple of versions of something like what you're asking, including my own which is up on [GitHub](https://github.com/jweinberg/JWLayoutViews)

Comment: Autoresizing masks will handle this particular use case just fine.

Comment: This is true, I didn't read the question as closely as I should have. But it does get closer to his second portion, about the Java Layout Managers.